# What is the best way to decipher a DB2 -302 error from Java?

Tags: db2, jdbctemplate

I am getting this error running an insert query for a single record:

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null,
>   DRIVER=3.62.56
>
> Exception: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException

I looked this up on IBM's help site, but there being no parameter index, I am stuck. The SQL state also seems to specify it is other than a value being too big.

The format of the query is `INSERT INTO [[TABLE_NAME]] VALUES (?,?,?,...)` using Spring's `JdbcTemplate.update(String sql, Object... params)`.

This being for work, I cannot post schema nor query. I am looking for general advice into debugging this issue. I already know using `Arrays.toString(Object[])` does not print out in SQL format.

Answer (score 0):

To find the explanation for SQLCODE -302 in the manual you need to search for SQL0302N (the general rule for DB2 SQLCODE values is this: "SQL" plus four digits, padded if necessary with zeros on the left, plus "N" for "negative" because -302 is a negative number).

If you have the DB2 command line processor installed, you can also use it to look up error codes:

```
db2 ? sql302
```

which would produce something like this:

> SQL0302N  The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN
>   statement
>         is out of range for its corresponding use.
>
> Explanation:
>
> The value of an input host variable was found to be out of range for
>   its use in the SELECT, VALUES, or prepared statement.

In other words, one of the bind variables in your `INSERT` is too large for the target column. You'll need to compare the table column definitions with the actual values you're trying to insert.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to mustaccio's answer you can also get the info from sql with SYSPROC.SQLERRM. Example:

```
values SYSPROC.SQLERRM ('SQL302', '', '', 'en_US', 0)

SQL0302N  The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement
  is out of range for its corresponding use.

Explanation:
...
```